# Having trouble locating `v8_base` while attempting to update a library

Tags: v8

I found [this](https://github.com/sony/v8eval) project by Sony which serves as a wrapper around the V8 engine that exposes *just* enough functionality to be useful.

As is, the project references V8 version 7.1.177. I was trying to update to version 7.9.317.31.

The following is the `v8gen` invocation:

`tools/dev/v8gen.py x64.release -- v8_use_snapshot=false v8_enable_i18n_support=false`

And the following is the Ninja invocation:

`ninja -v -C out.gn/x64.release`

The issue I'm having is that when I [change the version](https://github.com/sony/v8eval/blob/81638c7077abacb4dfe42ed7ef5d96d7350038ed/build.sh#L60) indicated in the build script I encounter a build error complaining about the directory `/v8/out.gn/x64.release/obj/v8_base` is missing. My guess is that `v8_base` is now called something else, but I can't find that documented anywhere.

I'm a bit out of my depth here so I'm not really sure where I should even start looking as far as documentation goes.

Comment: Which version are you trying to update to? Have you tried asking for help with that project? I can confirm that `v8_base` is gone; there are now `v8_base_without_compiler` and `v8_compiler` and you'll probably need both, but I'm just guessing here. -- Anything beyond the `v8` build target is considered internal implementation details not intended for public consumption and hence not documented or promised to be stable; use at your own risk.

Comment: Trying to update to 7.9.317.31. The current project links to `v8_libplatform`, `v8_base`, `v8_libbase`, `v8_libsampler`, `v8_init`, `v8_initializers`, `v8_nosnapshot`, and `torque_generated_initializers`. Naive question... Is there a way to "link to all the V8 things"?

Comment: The official V8 docs (https://v8.dev/docs/embed) recommend to build the `v8_monolith` target, then you have just one library to link against.

Comment: I'm going to give it a shot. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Follow up: Linking the monolith worked! Thanks @jmrk!